# How do I reset to the default Camera setting?

Tags: settings, unity-game-engine

When you first run Unity, it has that scene where an Area Light is acting like a sun, and the camera is a nice shade that allows you to clearly see around you.

I accidentally changed my settings on my Main Camera, and it has stayed there, and is a solid color of blue. How do I get the original camera settings back?

Answer (score 6):

Just click that little gear and reset it:

[image]

Comment: I set it to default as something else. I can open any of my Games or even make a new one and its still there

Answer (score 1):

Delete your main camera. Make a new camera. Drag it back into the hierarchy. Rename it to the name of your original camera. That should, in theory, give you all of the default settings if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a Skybox. Here's how to get it back

1. Select the `Main Camera` GameObject. Under the `Clear Flags` setting, select `Skybox`
2. Open the `Lighting` tab by going to `Window -> Lighting`
3. Under the `Environment Lighting` settings, change your Skybox to `Default-Skybox`
4. Profit.

   Pictures below

[image: Set Main Camera's Clear Flags to Skybox]

[image: Select Default-Skybox in Lighting]

Answer (score 0):

just set the scale in Main Camera for z-axis to -10 as it is set to 0 which renders camera preview with blue screen.
A screenshot is provided so i hope it may help you. [just change your settings as depicted in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP0b6.png)